# How to define variable of a matrix (not array)?Normalization, Min_of_Matrix, Max_

Tags: python, matrix, normalization

I am trying to normalize my data set within -1 and 1 in the matrix (10 rows, 3 columns)
When I define "lambda x", calculation is normalizing per one column, not per entire matrix

Briefly, how can I find MIN or MAX of an entire matrix?

Beginner question to define my X (i,j) 
X should the element of my matrix, instead of an array

MyMatrix being a 10 row, 3 column dataset

`MyMatrix = pd.read_csv("MyMatrix.csv")`

```
MyMatrix = MyMatrix.apply(pd.to_numeric)

MyMatrix = MyMatrix.apply(lambda x:(x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x)))
```

Comment: what is the object type of your matrix? numpy array of numpy arrays?

Comment: Just  updated it with my code. thanks

Comment: you want the numbers to scale from 0 to 1 or -1 to 1? normalization usually means 0 to 1， in case you want -1 to 1, just do normalization first then MyMatrix * 2 - 1 for every value, and if you know your numbers ranges from -1 to 1, maybe it is better to do (MyMatrix + 1)/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max:

```
max(MyMatrix.max())
```

Min:

```
min(MyMatrix.min())
```

Normalization:

```
(MyMatrix-min(MyMatrix.min()))/(max(MyMatrix.max())-min(MyMatrix.min()))
```

Comment: Yongkang "max(MyMatrix.max())" and same for min works, thanks a lot!   Indeed the correct term what I am doing might be "Scale down" .. For example suppose the max=100 will become to 1 but the minimum number (-70) will become -0.7 not (-1)..I dont know why normalization is popular, for me scaling down make more sense in mathematical aspect (in my problem at least) to do weighting of variables...

Comment: if you know the range of your input it's ok to use custom scaling, but I believe it makes very little difference on model performance, with different scale the parameters will also be able to adjust to it. the idea is to have all your input data scaled to a range so that the model will be able to pick better parameters, if the ranges of features varies greatly it would cause problems. (forgot what this problem is called, I always do standardization or normalization when possible)